# How to enter the data into the CoreData through barcode code?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, barcode

Hello I want to enter code to a table in core data comes this code by scanning a bar code and how can I code with matching array codes before you insert it into the database and then I want a condition when the application is running for the second time to examine existing in the database code

the barcode code

```
func barcodefunc(){
        // Get an instance of the AVCaptureDevice class to initialize a device object and provide the video
        // as the media type parameter.
        let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)

        // Get an instance of the AVCaptureDeviceInput class using the previous device object.
        var error:NSError?
        let input: AnyObject! = AVCaptureDeviceInput.deviceInputWithDevice(captureDevice, error: &error)

        if (error != nil) {
            // If any error occurs, simply log the description of it and don't continue any more.
            println("\(error?.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        // Initialize the captureSession object.
        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        // Set the input device on the capture session.
        captureSession?.addInput(input as AVCaptureInput)

        // Initialize a AVCaptureMetadataOutput object and set it as the output device to the capture session.
        let captureMetadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
        captureSession?.addOutput(captureMetadataOutput)

        // Set delegate and use the default dispatch queue to execute the call back
        captureMetadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
        captureMetadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = supportedBarCodes

        // Initialize the video preview layer and add it as a sublayer to the viewPreview view's layer.
        videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        videoPreviewLayer?.frame = view.layer.bounds
        view.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer)



        // Move the message label to the top view
        view.bringSubviewToFront(meseg)

        // Initialize QR Code Frame to highlight the QR code
        qrCodeFrameView = UIView()
        qrCodeFrameView?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
        qrCodeFrameView?.layer.borderWidth = 2
        view.addSubview(qrCodeFrameView!)
        view.bringSubviewToFront(qrCodeFrameView!)
    }

    func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [AnyObject]!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

        // Check if the metadataObjects array is not nil and it contains at least one object.
        if metadataObjects == nil || metadataObjects.count == 0 {
            qrCodeFrameView?.frame = CGRectZero
            meseg.text = "No QR code is detected"
            return
        }

        // Get the metadata object.
        let metadataObj = metadataObjects[0] as AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

        // Here we use filter method to check if the type of metadataObj is supported
        // Instead of hardcoding the AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode, we check if the type
        // can be found in the array of supported bar codes.
        if supportedBarCodes.filter({ $0 == metadataObj.type }).count > 0 {
            // If the found metadata is equal to the QR code metadata then update the status label's text and set the bounds
            let barCodeObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject(metadataObj as AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject) as AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
            qrCodeFrameView?.frame = barCodeObject.bounds

            if metadataObj.stringValue != nil {
                meseg.text = metadataObj.stringValue
            }
        }
    }
```

this coredata code

```
let entityDescripition = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Usercode", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)
        let task = Usercode(entity: entityDescripition!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
        code?.the_code = "ali"
        managedObjectContext?.save(nil)
```

Comment: Where's your code for core-data? It's fairly simple - once find the QR code you should be querying your core-data for the existing code. If it doesn't exist, do an insert into your `Entity`. If it does exist, then grab that record and update it.

Comment: im add core data code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some sample code. First you need to set up your Core Data Stack in the AppDelegate Have you done that? If so, here is the code to save to Core Data.

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Usercode",inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
let task = Usercode(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
task.the_code = "ali"

var error: NSError?
if !managedContext.save(&error) {
println("Could not save \(error), \(error?.userInfo)")
}
```